# Unit testing ArrayList

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

In my application I parse the contents of an XML file into two arrays. In my unit test how can I get these ArrayLists from the Activity under test so that I can test they are for example the right length and the contents are correct? With the method I am using at the moment the arrays are always null, although I know the parsing is working correctly. (The parsing method is called in the onCreate() method of the activity under test.)

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class TroubleShooterActivityTest {
private TroubleShooterActivity mActivity;
private Button mButton;
private TextView mTextView;
private ImageView mLogo;
private ArrayList<Page> mPageList;
private ArrayList<Answer> mAnswerList;
private int lengthPageArray = 7;
private int lengthAnswerArray = 7;

@Before    
public void setUp() throws Exception {        
    mActivity = new TroubleShooterActivity();        
    mActivity.onCreate(null);        
    mButton = (Button) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.troubleShooter); 
    mTextView = (TextView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.title);
    mLogo = (ImageView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.IntegralLogo); 
    mPageList = TroubleShooterActivity.pageList;
    mAnswerList = TroubleShooterActivity.answerList;
    }


@Test 
public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull(mTextView);
    assertNotNull(mLogo);
    assertNotNull(mButton);
    assertNotNull(mPageList);
    assertNotNull(mAnswerList);
}


     @Test
public void testArraysWereFilledCorrectly(){
    assertEquals(mPageList.size(), lengthPageArray);
    assertEquals(mAnswerList.size(), lengthAnswerArray);
}
```

Code from TroubleShooterActivity

```
public class TroubleShooterActivity extends OptionMenu {

/**Variables */ 
static ArrayList<Page> pageList;
 static ArrayList<Answer> answerList;




  /**  onCreate() is called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    parseXML();

    Button Select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.troubleShooter);
    /** assign behaviour to button*/
    Select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TroubleShooterActivity.this,     Question.class);
            intent.putExtra("NextPageID", 1); //Pass next page ID to Question class
            startActivity(intent);  
        }

    });


}

public void parseXML(){
    try {

        /** Try handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();

        /**Gets the input from the XML file stored in the res raw folder */

        InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.trouble_shooter_content));

        XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();

        /** assign our handler */
        xmlreader.setContentHandler(xmlHandler);
        xmlreader.parse(new InputSource(is.getByteStream()));


        pageList = XMLHandler.pageList;
        answerList = XMLHandler.answerList;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Let the user know about the error
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing more, not sure how to help--if they're static, and filled by `onCreate()`, they should have values. Do they in `@Before`? I don't like how you're doing all the work in `setUp`, though; IMO the tests should operate against the instance, and all the setup should do is instantiate and call onCreate.

Comment: Yes they are static and are filled by onCreate(). I was following the Android Activity testing tutorial which does all that work in the setUp.

Comment: It looks like the TroubleShooterActivity really returns null. We need some code of the TroubleShooterActivity in order to help you.

Comment: I have added the relevant TroubleShooterActivity code. The parsing does happens as the Question Activity relies on it and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there is an exception being caught and hidden away into your Toast call during the catch(Exception e).  Im not sure Robolectric fully initializes your resources so that you can make this call: getResources().openRawResource()

If you want to isolate the xml parsing code and fully test it and its results, you may consider moving the parsing code out of your Activity into its own class.  This way you don't even have to leverage robolectric to run your tests.

As a side note, are you sure that static is an appropriate modifier for your variables?  I think non-static should work just fine in this case.